# how to fix "fatal: could not create work tree dir 'WSL-Distribution-Switcher': No such file or directory"

Tags: git

im currently trying to install kali linux on my laptop and im stuck in this error. please help me to fix this. thanks!

i typed:

```
cd Desktop
cd Test(Blank folder in Desktop)
git clone https://github.com/RoliSoft/WSL-Distribution-Switcher.git

git clone https://github.com/RoliSoft/WSL-Distribution-Switcher.git
```

But I got below error:

> fatal: could not create work tree dir 'WSL-Distribution-Switcher': No such file or directory