# fatal: could not create work tree dir:no such file or directory

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm trying to clone my git repository resides in gitlab. While checking out files, I'm getting this error. Moreover, I verified that my current local folder where I tried to clone has permission to write.

I think it may be the possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54385814/how-to-fix-fatal-could-not-create-work-tree-dir-wsl-distribution-switcher-n).
As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54385814/how-to-fix-fatal-could-not-create-work-tree-dir-wsl-distribution-switcher-n) question has no answer, I just asked again.

Kindly help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The cause for the problem is `Ransomeware Protection` in `Windows Security` was enabled. If it is enabled, Windows does not allow untrusted websites to access our protected folder. Disabling `Ransomware Protection` is not a recommended one. You can allow websites which you trust to access specific folder through `Allow an app through Controlled folder access` option.

Comment: This right here. Thanks for saving me potentially hours of heartburn

Comment: The same happened to me while cloning through GitHub Desktop. I disabled RealTime Protection in Windows Security and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a git bash session on Windows, try again in a regular CMD (your %PATH% should already reference Git).

Again, if you are on Windows, make sure to use the [latest Git For Windows (2.21)](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)

Answer (score 0):

After cloning the gitlab project, it might have given you the folder name where it was created.
Something like 
$ git clone yourHttpgitclonelink
Cloning into 'SampleProjects'...

then you have to navigate inside SampleProjects directory by using 
$ cd SampleProjects
if you are able to navigate inside sample project, that means everything is working fine for you and you will be able to checkout your project by using command
$ git checkout yourbranchname

In case you are not able to navigate inside "SampleProjects" directory you will be getting the error "bash: cd: SampleProjects: No such file or directory"

That means there was a problem while cloning the project, That problem could be due to your organisation domain restrictions or credential restrictions.

for domain restriction problems you have to ask permission from your IT team to provide the access to the URL.

Comment: I've the proper privilege to access my organisation URL. In addition to that, I could able to clone at `C:` drive and I could not do the same in other drives like `D:`